# Using take(1) with an Observable<boolean>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Reading [through this article](https://engineering.datorama.com/i-built-the-ngrx-demo-app-with-akita-heres-the-result-57f83fe92192) and it uses the following `CanActivate` check to see whether the user is allowed to navigate to the home page:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
 return this.authQuery.isLoggedIn$.pipe(
   take(1),
   switchMap((isLoggedIn) => {
     if (!isLoggedIn) {
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
     }
     return of(isLoggedIn);
   })
);
```

I'm wondering what the purpose of `take(1)` is?  Since the `isLoggedIn$` is an instance of `Observable<boolean>`, it seems there is always only 1 to take?

Comment: Some good [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10556) on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will take only once its kinda the same as reading snapshot.

In this case of `canActivate` its a question if you need it since you are NOT subscribing, so angular will handle freeing resources since you are returning observable. So I would not use take in this case

`take` is important if you are subscribing so you stop listening to observables when you dont need them